# How to call a function with it's parameters stored in a variable python

Tags: python, function, tuples

I have a variable that contains a function, and one that has the parameters I want to pass to it as a tuple. How can I call that function with those parameters?

```
# Example
func = self.my_func 
params = (1, 2, 3)

func(params)
```

I want to do something like the code above, but it doesn't work since that syntax just takes the tuple as a single parameter. What is the right syntax to do this?

Comment: `func(*params)`